# Measuring bluetooth signal strength via AppleScript on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bluetooth, applescript

So I just read [this article](http://theappleblog.com/2009/06/11/how-to-proximity-automation/). What I'm wondering is, is there any way to determine bluetooth signal strength quantitatively, whether using AppleScript or some other language on Mac OS X? I'd like to implement something like this, except the 30-foot range mentioned in the article is a bit high, IMHO. I'd like it to work when I'm more than, say, five feet away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [Cocoa IOBluetoothDevice docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothDevice_h/Classes/IOBluetoothDevice/CompositePage.html), it appears there is no way to query signal strength.

You can only query if the device is connected or not.